# BI Publisher - Display Image using the URL in RTF

Tags: bi-publisher, xml-publisher, oracle-xml-publisher

I am using Word 2019 to create RTF Templates for BI Publisher

I have a table **ITEM_IMAGE** that has a column **IMAGE_URL** that contains the URL of the image on the internet

I need to display the Image using the URL that is there on the field

How can I do that on MS Word 2019?

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/38870/in-microsoft-word-how-can-i-link-to-an-image-from-the-web-which-updates : Does this fix your issue?

Comment: IncludePicture expects fixed path. It's not allowing relative path of the URL that's stored in the column

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert any exiting image on to the word document.
2. Right click on the image and select format picture.
3. In right pane under Layout tab, add below code in alt text field.

`url:{IMAGE_URL}`

where IMAGE_URL is your column name

Comment: Option doesn't exist for Word 2019

Comment: @ImranHemani I have tried this in 2016. Find alt text option for image and add it there. Please check below document

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/everything-you-need-to-know-to-write-effective-alt-text-df98f884-ca3d-456c-807b-1a1fa82f5dc2